# Finding the names and the year of the movies that have at least 5 actors

Tags: ms-access

Given database of the website "eMovies" that manage data about cinema movies.

> Write in SQL query that finds the names and the year of the movies that have at least 5 actors.

[image]

**My attempt:**

The idea: to do a natural joint between "Movies" and "ActorsMovies" tables, and then to count the rows with the same MovieID, and then to check if count>5

I succeded to count the rows thank's to @Phil's advice, but still I need the name of the movies and the year,

Here is my start:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year, MovieName
FROM Movies, ActrorsMovies
SELECT Count(ActorsMovies.MovieID) 
FROM ActorsMovies
GROUP BY ActorsMovies.MovieID
HAVING (((Count(ActorsMovies.ActorID))>5));
```

This code does not work

---

EDIT: another attempt

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Movies.Year, Movies.MovieName
 FROM Movies, ActorsMovies
 GROUP BY ActorsMovies.MovieID
 HAVING Count(ActorsMovies.ActorID)>5;
```

Comment: You need a JOIN condition(among other things) in there otherwise you get a cardinal join(every row is multiplied with every other row from the second table)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have deleted the previous question and posted this one.

Comment: "At least 5" would translate to me as "> 4" or ">= 5" I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close

```
SELECT M.MovieID, M.MovieName, M.Year 
  FROM Movies M
 INNER JOIN ActorsMovies AM 
         ON AM.MovieID = M.MovieID
 GROUP BY M.MovieID, M.MovieName, M.Year
HAVING COUNT(AM.ActorID) > 5
```

You could probably just use count(*) > 5

Answer (score 1):

This code works in T-SQL and should work in Ms Access:

```
SELECT COUNT(M.MovieID) as 'Count', M.MovieName, M.Year FROM Movies M
INNER JOIN ActorsMovies AM ON AM.MovieID = M.MovieID
INNER JOIN Actors A ON AM.ActorID = A.ActorID
GROUP BY M.MovieID, M.MovieName, M.Year
HAVING COUNT(M.MovieID) > 5
```

I also recommend not to use `Year` as a field name because it's a reserverd keyword in Ms Access and *may* cause problems:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: This probably works but join to Actors is not necessary